# Using lags or monthly categorical features for recognizing the seasonality with DeepAR and TFT from pytorch-forecasting

Tags: forecasting, feature-engineering, deepar

I try to forecast monthly sales with the help of DeepAR and Temporal Fusion Transformer from pytorch-forecasting. The data I use has monthly seasonality, and the seasonality is the same or at least very similar for different countries.

While generating the TimeSeriesDataSet with pytorch-forecasting I could set the parameter lags for the target variable. The documentation says about it:

> Lags can be useful to indicate seasonality to the models

I’m not sure if this is the better option than using the month or maybe month and country in a combination as a categorical feature to simplify the recognition of the seasonality.

Did anyone have own experience with this topic or an explanation what choice would be the best?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

DeepAR algorithm automatically generates feature for time series. Read more here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/deepar_how-it-works.html

- You can also add your own custom feature ( both categorical and continuous ) for each Timeseries. (e.g. Public holidays etc )
- It works well when you have multiple time series with more than 300 data points for each.
- All time series should have same frequency.

Benchmark on DeepAR and TFT is in your hands, I guess TFT will outperform.